# How can I permanently map the vim command :W to :w?

Tags: vim

Sometimes in vim I am holding shift when I save, and wind up doing `:W`. How can I set my vimrc to recognize `:W` as `:w`?

Comment: You could turn this around and also map `;` to `:` so that you won't need Shift at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, too, have a "lazy" shift finger, so I have a number of command aliases:

```
" "Aliases" for commonly used commands+lazy shift finger:
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=file -range=% -bang W         <line1>,<line2>write<bang> <args>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=file -range=% -bang Write     <line1>,<line2>write<bang> <args>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=file -range=% -bang Wq        <line1>,<line2>wq<bang> <args>
command! -bar                                  -bang Wqall     wqa<bang>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=file -range=% -bang We        <line1>,<line2>w<bang> | e <args>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=file -count   -bang Wnext     <count>wnext<bang> <args>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=file -count   -bang Wprevious <count>wprevious<bang> <args>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=file          -bang E         edit<bang> <args>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=file          -bang Edit      edit<bang> <args>
command! -bar                                  -bang Q         quit<bang>
command! -bar                                  -bang Quit      quit<bang>
command! -bar                                  -bang Qall      qall<bang>
command! -bar -nargs=? -complete=option              Set       set <args>
command! -bar -nargs=? -complete=help                Help      help <args>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=file          -bang Make      make<bang> <args>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=buffer        -bang Bdel      bdel<bang> <args>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=buffer        -bang Bwipe     bwipe<bang> <args>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=file          -bang Mksession mksession<bang> <args>
command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=dir           -bang Cd        cd<bang> <args>
command! -bar                                        Messages  messages
command! -bar -nargs=+ -complete=file          -bang Source    source<bang> <args>
```

The reason I have a number of duplicated commands such as `W` and `Write` is because I have enough user defined commands that Vim might complain about ambiguous use of user commands if I don't.  (See: `:help user-cmd-ambiguous`)

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to map a key but create a command that behaves the same way as w(rite) does.
Just write this into $HOME/.vimrc:

```
command W write
```

Comment: I would recommend fully supporting the :write command: `command -bar -nargs=* -complete=file -range=% -bang Write <line1>,<line2>write<bang> <args>`

Comment: @Heptite Completely agree. I didn't even think about it so deeply.